# Properly dispose of view and viewmodel using INavigationAware and Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I use the Prism IRegionManager to navigate between screens:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate( RegionNames.MainContentRegion, uri );
```

I have a Person Edit View that I navigate to in the above manner and I always want this screen to be reloaded whenever a new person to edit is selected.  To do this I'm returning false in the IsNavigationTarget method of INavigationAware. I'm also using mvvm and there's a PersonEditViewModel for this Person Edit View.

What I'm worried about is the application never disposing the previous PersonEditViewModel.  I know it's not disposed automatically because IsNavigationTarget is called for all the previously created PersonEditViewModels.  I put a break point in to tell.

What's a good way to dispose of the view and view model?  since I know I'm always going to return false in IsNavigationTarget I would rather dispose them and free up some space.  I was thinking maybe I could do something in the OnNavigatedFrom method?...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at `IRegionMemberLifetime` and the [RegionMemberLifetimeBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.behaviors.regionmemberlifetimebehavior%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx).